# Break ContentControl on multiple pages in word online using office-js

Tags: office-js, word-contentcontrol

I am inserting some html into word document using insertHTML method but the html is long and If there is any content above that html the whole ContentControl drops to the 2nd page of the document to accommodate it in a single page. Is there any way to make ContentControl breakable on multiple pages? Here is my code

```
if (Array.isArray(content)) {
   for (const chunk of content) {
       insertedRange = context.document.body.insertHtml(chunk, options.location);
       context.document.body.insertHtml(lineBreakBlob, options.location);
       if (options.doWrap) {
          const insertedContentControl: Word.ContentControl = insertedRange.insertContentControl();
          insertedContentControl.appearance = 'Hidden';
          insertedContentControl.tag = options.title ? options.title : 'data';
          await insertedContentControl.context.sync();
       }
   }
}
```

screenshot of the issue I am facing, the content should start direct below the above text.
[image]

Comment: If you _manually_ create a content control with the same content, would it break on a page end or be pushed to the next page?